# Polar equation of the curve y = sinx

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I am looking for the polar equation of the following curve given in Cartesian Coordinates.

y = sinx

Any kind of hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why would you need it in polar form?

Comment: There are several reasons, 
First is curiosity, sin is a simple function in Cartesian Coordinates, I wonder whether it is easy to express that function in polar coordinates.
Second is that I tried to solve a question in a difficult way. For this, I need to express this curve in terms of polar coordinates (solved for r). 
The third reason is fun. I like identities.

Comment: Curiosity is always appreciated...:)

Answer (score 2):

With $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$, this becomes
$$ r \sin(\theta) = \sin(r \cos(\theta))$$

That's as simple as it gets: in particular you're not going to get an explicit closed form for $r$ as a function of $\theta$, or $\theta$ as a function of $r$.

Comment: The parametric form $\theta=\arctan(\sin(t)/t),r=\sqrt{\sin^2(t)+t^2}$ is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

As $$\tan(\theta)=\frac yx=\frac{\sin(x)}x=\text{sinc}(x),$$ where $\text{sinc}$ denotes the cardinal sine function, you have

$$\color{green}{r=\sqrt{(\text{sinc}^{-1}(\tan(\theta)))^2+\sin^2(\text{sinc}^{-1}(\tan(\theta)))}}.$$

Unfortunately, the inverse $\text{sinc}$ function is a wild animal.